# Progressbar with dynamic timer in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Mat progress bar

> https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview

using following code to increment the count, this progress bar is working on static values but when i pass dynamic values in `this.timeLeft` then progress bar is not incrementing it's counter properly sometimes it gets completed before the timer.

```
 <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="determinateCnt"></mat-progress-bar>
  this.timeLeft =30;
  startTimer() {
  this.startCounter(); 
  this.init_flag=true;
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(this.timeLeft > 0) {
      this.timeLeft--;
      if(this.timeLeft==0)
      {
        this.pauseTimer();
      }
    } else {
      this.timeLeft = 30;
    }
  },1000)
}
  startCounter() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.determinateCnt += 3.5;
    }, 1000);
  }
   clearTimer() {
      this.determinateCnt=0;
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
```

Any solution Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a dynamic value in this.timeLeft, in this case it's 30, the value of your progress bar is still increasing by 3.5 every second (out of it's max, 100).

If this.timeLeft would be any other value, the progress bar would still increase with 3.5. Because 3.5 is hardcoded.

instead of
`this.determinateCnt += 3.5;`
you should use
`this.determinateCnt += 100/this.timerDuration*(this.timerDuration-this.timeLeft)`

You need to add `this.timerDuration` yourself. Set it once, right after you set `this.timeLeft`. So `this.timerDuration = this.timeLeft;`.

An example:
First second the progress would be: `100/30*1=3.333`
Third it would be: `100/30*3=9.9999` (10% of the 100%, 3 of 30..)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks i tried this but it's not working progress bar is not working